# Styling the content section of an Expander control

Tags: wpf, styles, expander

How do you apply a style to the content section of an Expander control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
    <Style x:Key="ListItem" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2"/>

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultBorder}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                        <Grid>
                             <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="0,10,0,10" >
                                <ContentControl Margin="24,0,0,0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I needed the `ContentControl`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the Content property of expander is of type Object, there are no restrictions on what you can put in a ContentControl.You can apply whatever style you want,depending on what you want to display and how you want to display them.